# Why does an exhaustively returning switch fail to compile if there is code following it?

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, static-analysis, unreachable-code

Why does this code fail to compile when using `noImplicitReturns`...

```
function foo(bar: "a"): number
{
    switch (bar)
    {
        case "a":
            return 1;
    }

    let unreachable;
}
```

> error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

...while this code compiles with not so much as a peep?

```
function foo(bar: "a"): number
{
    switch (bar)
    {
        case "a":
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: On the assumption that it is a bug, I've reported it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18882